# Does negative real solution exist?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Question: To show that the equation $4x^3 = 9x^2 - 10x - 8$ has a negative real solution (i.e. a solution $<0$).

My Attempt:

Given equation: $4x^3 = 9x^2 - 10x - 8$

Let $f(x) = 4x^3 - 9x^2 + 10x + 8$

We have:

$f(0) = 4(0)^3 - 9(0)^2 + 10(0) + 8 = 8$

$f(-1) = 4(-1)^3 - 9(-1)^2 + 10(-1) + 8 = -4 - 9 - 10 + 8 = -15$

Therefore, $f(-1) < 0 < f(0)$, which means that $f(x)$ has a real root between $-1$ and $0$ by the Intermediate Value Theorem. Since this root is negative, it is a negative real solution of the given equation.

Therefore, the given equation has a negative real solution, as required.

Am I right ?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: I think you might also add a short note on IVT prerequisities (assumptions) and point out the given function satisfies them, hence the theorem actually applies to it. It may look just as a nit-picking, but _sometimes_ people try to use theorems which do not apply to their problems, so a habit of checking the assumptions makes you safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is right. Moreover, it is the only real root of the equation, as there can't be odd number of complex roots.

Comment: To establish that that is the only real root, you need to establish there are no other real roots, which may be accomplished by showing there are no turning points.